# upload a file using php script without leaving that page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to upload a file in html using php script.

```
<html>
<body>
  <form id='importPfForm' enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://localhost/js/upload.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
    Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploaded_file" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the "upload.php" contains the following code:

```
<?php
$upload_key = 'uploaded_file';
if (isset($_FILES[$upload_key])) {
    try {
        $error = $_FILES[$upload_key]['error'];
        switch ($error) {
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                throw new Exception('Exceeded upload_max_filesize');
            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                throw new Exception('Exceeded MAX_FILE_SIZE');
            case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
                throw new Exception('Incomplete file uploaded');
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                throw new Exception('No file uploaded');
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
                throw new Exception('No tmp directory');
            case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
                throw new Exception('Can\'t write data');
            case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
                throw new Exception('Extension error');
        }
        $finfo    = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
        $name     = $_FILES[$upload_key]['name'];
        $tmp_name = $_FILES[$upload_key]['tmp_name'];
        $size     = $_FILES[$upload_key]['size'];
        if ($size > 350000)
            throw new Exception('Exceeded 350KB limit');
        if (!is_uploaded_file($tmp_name))
            throw new Exception('Not an uploaded file');
        $type = $finfo->file($tmp_name);
        if ($type === false)
            throw new Exception('Failed to get MimeType');
        if ($type !== 'text/plain; charset=us-ascii')
            throw new Exception('Only csv available');
        $new_name = dirname(__FILE__).'/upload/'.$name;
    echo  $new_name;
        if (is_file($new_name))
            throw new Exception("The file {$new_name} already exists");
        if (!move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$new_name))
            throw new Exception('Failed to move uploaded file');
        echo "File successfully uploaded as {$new_name}";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

But this method opens a new web page. I want to perform the function without leaving the web page and i need to use the variable  `$new_name` in html page. What is the modification i need to perform in my html page? I'm pretty sure this works via some kind of ajax request thing. but I have no idea what I'm talking about. I'm not big on ajax or javascript, but this is a function i use very frequently and I'd like to learn how it works so I can implement it when i need to now and in the future.

Comment: Add an hidden `iframe` to your page, setup your form to post to it (`target` attribute) and make so your php script returns a html page in which a bit of javascript tells the parent page that the upload succeeded/failed

Comment: Check following links. You may try Ajax, HTML5 or Flash uploader. http://www.uploadify.com/ http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/ http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-ajax-file-upload/

Comment: or just use http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ - it is very good.

Comment: @Dinoop have you ever done some researches about Ajax and how it works? I don't want to hurt you though yourself spoke that you "don't know talking about". Btw. even though it is not wrong, you don't need to define 'http://localhost' in the action attribute, except you want to submit the data to an external site..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two choices really here. You could use the following code as the action for the form and then have the php in the same file.

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>
```

Or

```
header("Location: upload.html?new_name=value_of_new_name");
```

In the upload.php where its successful, then in upload.html you can use `$_GET['new_name']` to retrieve the value of `$new_name`

Comment: <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> is open to XSS attacks... Avoid.